# android WIFI state when phone is locked

Tags: android

when android phone is in SLEEP State 0r Locked State What is the state of WIFI ?
is it active or not?

Comment: I believe it depends on the phone's settings.  There is an "always on" setting that you can set on some phones to have it always be on.

Comment: I am seeing a pattern that it locks when in sleep.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Must be active, I've downloaded stuff from the Market place whilst my phone (HTC Desire) has gone to sleep, and the download has finished the next time I unlock (wake) it.

Comment: Nope. It depends on settings.

Comment: I had a quick look, if the Wifi is ON and I'm downloading and the phone sleeps the download continues. I couldn't find a setting to change the behaviour. Obviously if Wifi is OFF it's state will not change. So just for my own information, what Setting would change the ON behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

It's depend on application. By default in Sleep mode wifi state is inactive. Application need to take a wifi lock to keep it acive.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on many factors, including those that others have metioned:

In your android settings, wireless settings, advanced settings- there is a wifi sleep policy which can somewhat answer your question.

However, an application (with the appropriate permission) can change this setting or temporarily change it to bypass the setting.

"Sleep" is pretty vague because some consider this when your display is turned off, however a device actually has different levels of sleep, and deep sleep.  Deep sleep doesn't kick in as soon as the display is off, and often these rules are referring to deep sleep.

Applications can also obtain a wifi lock (with the appropriate permission) which will wake up the Wi-Fi radio even though the phone is in deep sleep.